# notifydatasetchange() not working in post method of asynch task

Tags: android, listview, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a custom listview and its data getting change frequently.So for updating listview I have registered a broad cast receiver in the activity and initialising the list again and calling notifydataset change in post method.But list data not getting change.For the temparary solution I have intialised adapter object againg and setting it againg.But I feel its not good option.Can any one tell me how to do this task.Her is the code of my broadcast receiver.

```
  private  class ListenChange extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

            if(intent.getAction().equals(ConversationListActivityNew.action_change))
            {
                if(is_activity_visible) {
                    if (uri != null&&adapter!=null) {
//                          adapter =null;
//                          adapter = new MessageAdapterNew(MessageListActivityNew.this, uri, searched_text);
//                          setListAdapter(adapter);
                             new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>()
                             {

                                 @Override
                                 protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                                     adapter.getData(MessageListActivityNew.this,uri);
                                     return null;
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                                     Log.e("notifying row","notifying row");
                                     MessageListActivityNew.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                     super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                                 }
                             }.execute();

                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please mention the reason for negative vote.

Comment: Debug and check you're getting data in uri or not. If getting then what data it is.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi commented code is working fine .So data in uri is coming for sure.

Comment: Its due to the Asynctask. Why don't you work with UI Thread??

runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Here the actions you want to perform
    }
});

Comment: @AnshulTyagi ok I can try this

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Dint work:(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909239/how-to-update-listview-from-broadcastreceiver  he also asked same type of question..look at it